# Solution to PHP error Undefined property: EE::$cache

Tags: php-errors

We are now preparing to upgrade to Expression Engine 3.5.4 from EE version 2.5.5.

We are implementing up-gradation on local test server before implementing it on live server to make sure that we do not run into any issues.

Currently running structure Version 3.3.9 in EE 2.5.5 website is incompatible to EE version 3.5.4.

So we recently purchased structure version 4.1.12 from https://eeharbor.com/structure.

But when we  are upgrading( as per the instruction from http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/upgrading/) structure version 3.3.9 to 4.1.12   from  EE2.5.5 website running in local test server  shows the PHP Error.(Screenshot Attached).

Actually it is upgraded to 4.1.12 as per the screenshot1. But when click on module settings (screenshot2) shows this error and the same error occurred in the front end when we try to access the index.php.

SERVER DETAILS

Test Sever- XAMPP

Server API -Apache 2.0 Handler.

Apache Version - Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30

PHP Version 5.6.30

EE Version - 2.5.5

Current structure Version 3.3.9

Upgrading to  structure Version 4.1.12

ERROR IN FRONT END -
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: EE::$cache
Filename: helpers/eeharbor_ee2_helper.php
Line Number: 229

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet-backup\system\expressionengine\third_party\structure\helpers\eeharbor_ee2_helper.php on line 229

ERROR IN BACK END-

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Addons_modules::$cache
Filename: helpers/eeharbor_ee2_helper.php
Line Number: 229

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet-backup\system\expressionengine\third_party\structure\helpers\eeharbor_ee2_helper.php on line 229

Kindly send the solution as early as possible.

Thanks in advance.......

Shiny muhammed.

Comment: Where is screenshots?

Comment: Screen shot 1 data  in Modules Page - Structure - Create pages, generate navigation, manage content through a simple interface and build robust sites faster than ever. - 4.1.12 Installed - Remove

Comment: You removed structure.. but EE2 entries will lost the redirection URL and parent template setting of structure

Comment: Also can you try this again passing `$config['database']['expressionengine']['cache_on'] = FALSE` in your config file? and check for above errors again?

Comment: Screen shot 2 - Clicking on ModuleSettings in Structure Module Page Screen shot3-ERROR IN BACK END Screen Shot4-ERROR IN FRONT END

Comment: $config['database']['expressionengine']['cache_on'] = FALSEsolved the error by commenting two cases Case

Answer (score 0):

$config['database']['expressionengine']['cache_on'] = FALSE - Not worked.
solved the error by commenting two cases **case 'get':** and **case 'set':** in **public function cache($mode, $key = false, $data = false, $persistent = true)** of  **helpers/eeharbor_ee2_helper.php(Comment line no. from 228 to 237)**.After that error removed,front end loaded correctly, checked all links and they r working properly.In back end got the module settings page of structure 4.1.12.